# Set delegate object for custom class

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I made a custom view.
I set two starting methods,
1. initWithFrame (for code initialization)
2. initWithCoder (for storyboard initialization)

In my custom class

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // [self setUp] method contain the code to run the delegate.
        [self setUp];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // [self setUp] method contain the code to run the delegate.
        [self setUp];
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then, I add a View to storyboard and change the class at identity inspector.
I connect the view to the viewcontroller property.

I set the delegate and data source

In my view controller

```
@interface ViewController () <UIControlViewDataSource, UIControlViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIControlView *controlView;

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.controlView.delegate = self;
    self.controlView.dataSource = self;
}
```

The initWithCoder is running before viewDidLoad,

Because of it the delegate will never run because the initWithCoder in my custom class is running before I set the delegate in viewDidLoad in my view controller.
And the delegate property will have NULL value.

How could I set the delegate?

Comment: why you think , before setting delegate no initWithCoder should called ?

Comment: @pawan initWithCoder run [self setUp] method that contains code to pool data from the delegate method, if the delegate haven't set yet, the method can't run

Answer (score 1):

If you are instantiating these objects from a xib or storyboard (which it looks like you are based on the `IBOutlet`, you should set your delegate in `-(void)awakeFromNib`

At this point all the outlets will have been set.

You shouldn't have to depend on the order in which objects get instantiated. You should let them all get instantiated, the outlets set and then do whatever you need to do with your delegate

Comment: No luck, It's right that the awakeFromNib on the viewcontroller is running before initWithCoder in the custom class, but I can't set the delegate because the custom class is not initialized yet and I can't access it's property.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not getting the delegate set, but rather that your object requires a delegate for construction. A delegate should be an optional property.

Whatever operation your UIView requires its delegate for is likely something that can be pushed out of the actual constructor. If you want to have the delegate set automatically during the nib loading process, you could declare it as an IBOutlet property in your view. It will still be set after it is initialized though.

Without getting more detail about why you need to call the delegate, it's impossible to say where you could defer that logic to.